# Use "show tables" as a derived table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to combine "`show tables like`" as a derived table in a join.

This works:

```
  show tables like 'table_name_pattern_%'
```

However I cannot figure out how to make this work

```
  select i.* from table i
  left join (
      show tables like 'table_name_pattern_%'
  ) a on i.id=mid(a.`columnname_from_show_tables`, 20)
```

Any ideas, or is show tables a special statement that can't be joined?

I'm on MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbName'
```

Then:

```
 select i.* from table i
  left join (
 SELECT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbName'
      AND TABLE_NAME like 'table_name_pattern_%'
  ) a on i.id=mid(a.`TABLE_NAME`, 20)
```